How to create a recursive graphql input with nestjs?
I want to create a recursive input for one of my graphql queries and add filters to have the possibility to create groups of filters.
A basic filter must have an id, a value and an operator.
A group of filters must have a condition (and/or) and a filters array which is either a basic filter or another group filters.
This is what I've done so far.
import { ArgsType, createUnionType, Field, InputType } from '@nestjs/graphql';

@InputType()
class MyFilterInput {
  @Field()
  id: string;

  @Field(() => String, { nullable: true })
  value: string | null;

  @Field(() => String)
  operator: string;
}

@InputType()
class MyFilterGroupInput {
  @Field(() => String)
  condition: string;

  @Field(() => [MyFilterGroupOrFilterInput])
  filters: Array<typeof MyFilterGroupOrFilterInput>;
}

const MyFilterGroupOrFilterInput = createUnionType({
  name: 'MyFilterGroupOrFilter',
  types: () => [MyFilterInput, MyFilterGroupInput] as const,
  resolveType(value) {
    if (value.id) {
      return MyFilterInput;
    }
    if (value.condition) {
      return MyFilterGroupInput;
    }
    return null;
  },
});

@ArgsType()
export class MyPaginationInput {
  @Field(() => [MyFilterGroupInput], { nullable: true })
  readonly filters?: MyFilterGroupInput[];

  @Field({ nullable: true })
  readonly search?: string;
}

When starting the server I have this error:
Error: Cannot determine a GraphQL input type null for the \"filters\". Make sure your class is decorated with an appropriate decorator.
I have a feeling it is because the union type references the class which also references the union, becoming a cyclic dependency.
How can I solve this?
